# How to create a registry entry from a c# application?

Tags: c#

I am developing a windows application in .NET framework, using C#. At the time of application installation I want to write into the registry a certain value. So I have two questions regarding this :

1. How can I execute a code for creating a registry entry at time of installation or there is some settings in the framework which allows us to do so ?
2. I don't want to create a new node in the registry, can I use some common place anywhere, in the registry or an existing node where I can store my value without affecting the local system settings ?

Please help me out.

Thanks,

Bibhu

Comment: How did you decide that you want to store your settings in the registry?  Just because?  I would strongly suggest using [Application Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4s6c3a0.aspx) instead that way you don't have any dependencies on the registry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Microsoft.Win32.Registry class to read or write to the Windows registry.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.aspx

It's considered bad form to just drop data values into existing registry keys.  You should create a key path identified by your company and/or application name and put your registry stuff there.  This is a courtesy to the end user who may want to remove all your application cruft after they remove your application from their system.

Answer (score 2):

Convention holds that you should probably create a new node under the `Software` node. There's plenty of [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5e7chcf.aspx) on MSDN about creating registry keys.

Answer (score 1):

1) Here is a good tutorial on how to write to the registry from C#: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/modifyregistry.aspx

2) You can and should create a new key to store your settings, that way you are guaranteed to not interfere with anyone else's.  Generally, settings for the whole computer are stored under `HKLM/Software/<your company>/<your application>/`, and registry settings for an individual user are stored under `HKLU/Software/<your company>/<your application>/`

Answer (score 1):

Creating a new node (Under HKLM/Software/YourCompany/YourApp) is the proper thing to do here.

Additionally, the normal problem with writing to the registry is that you need to have administrator rights to do this.  However, if you use an msi-based installer, you must have administrator rights to run the installation anyway, and the installation will be able to write to the registry.  Just don't plan on ever changing that entry from your app later, as many users won't be able to.

Answer (score 1):

First, since you are only trying to write to the registry during the installation, you can modify your MSI file to include registry modifications.  This article will help in this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb458038.aspx

This way you aren't adding extra C# code for a deployment-only task.  If you wanted to continue to modify the registry after installation, you could add commands to do so inside C# but this doesn't seem to be a requirement.

As for where to install this information, I HIGHLY recommend that you create your own node for this.  This is what the registry is for.  If you start mixing information from two or more applications inside the same area, you are going to run into trouble.  Just create your own location, following the conventions of the registry.