# How to add program into Control Panel Programs with C# or cmd

Tags: c#, windows, addremoveprograms, default-programs

I have a program file. And I want to add this program into Control Panel Programs like this:[image]

How can I do that with C# code or cmd ?

Comment: You mean into the add/remove programs list? Use an installer generator to install your program, it will do that automatically for you.

Comment: I have an .exe file witch downloads my other program from internet and setup it. But this program doesn't add program into Control Panel Programs. I need a code for add this program into Control Panel Programs at the setup time

Answer (score 0):

To add an entry to that list, you need to create a subkey in the registry. Go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\` and check the entries there. Basically you need to create a key with a GUID as the name and below that a set of values, the most important being `DisplayName` and `UninstallString`.

Comment: I need to do this with C#

Comment: You'll find plenty of information about how to write to the registry with C#. There are a few starting points in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338322/how-to-create-a-registry-entry-from-a-c-sharp-application